# Does electrical conduit in a cinderblock wall need to be covered before being plastered over?

Tags: cinderblock

I have a receptacle in my kitchen cinder block wall and have chiseled a channel in the cider block for the Romex™ but I think the Romex™ needs to be in conduit like in this picture.

https://www.energyefficientbuild.com/images/RosO1-20080919-013a.jpg

Do I need to put a cover over the chiseled channel before I plaster over it or can I plaster right over the conduit?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify if this is a picture of your actual installation or if this is something you grabbed off the internet somewhere. If it's just a "representative picture", please show us pics of your actual install.

Comment: That picture is the actual install. The link is off the web.

Answer (score 1):

NM can be in the hollow cavity’s of block walls but not embedded in a cutout.
When run in block walls, if exiting the wall conduit would be needed on the outside unless a surface covering is provided (a furring strip on either side with 1/2” plywood or Sheetrock) is another way to do it. Your actual work might provide more detail.

Comment: I can put the NM in conduit and secure it to the wall. Is it ok to cover the 3-4 inches of conduit that is cut into the wall with plaster?

Comment: You can cover the conduit in plaster that is ok if conduit was not used “nail plates” to cover the nm wiring would be rwquired.

Comment: I like the idea of the nail plate directly under the receptacle to cover the wire in the channel of the cinder block. I can put the rest of the wire in conduit but I was wondering, since the wire will be behind a kitchen cabinet and won't be exposed, does code require it to be in conduit? I understand the reasoning of conduit if the wire is exposed but if it's behind a secured cabinet you can't accidentally come in contact with it.

Comment: Behind a built in cabinet would not be exposed. I have attached furring strips to concrete then screwed plywood to the strips to cover electrical work. Is the receptacle above the counter in that case a couple inches of nail plate to protect the wires would meet code.

Comment: Yes, the romex is behind and below the counter. I will get some nail plates to cover the romex in the channel cut into the cinder block going to the receptacle. I will then attach the romex to the wall going down to the floor and into the basement. Thanks Ed.

Comment: If you like an answer or comment give it an up vote or a check mark if you accept that answer it will help others find an answer to a similar question and give thanks for the help.